# A network of anonymous content sharing

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, online-piracy

Am building an anonymous private network, meaning anyone can put whatever they want, As the network Admin, I won't sue or grudge anyone for whatever they host in the network.

Now let's say within this network, users share pirated content, if the law sues one of these users, will I be forced to bring down these users? while my main policy of this network is anonymous content sharing?

Is there a way these users can get away with sharing whatsoever content they want? all I want is a place of freedom where the law cannot act.

How can I allow users to carry out any activities(illegal/legal) without the law being involved?

Comment: @feetwet  Would you kindly share your insights on this

Comment: "a place of freedom where the law cannot act" doesn't exist when you're talking about communications and IP rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the U.S., under Section 230, which is part of the [DMCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act), as a host you don't have any liability so long as you meet certain standards, including providing contact information to which someone claiming copyright infringement can send a takedown notice which the host promptly honors if made and if it is not superficially absurd (e.g. a claim directed at a photo of a passage in a historic King James Bible).

Under recently passed legislation called the [CLOUD Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLOUD_Act) (enacted in March of 2018), which "allow[s] federal law enforcement to compel U.S.-based technology companies via warrant or subpoena to provide requested data stored on servers regardless of whether the data are stored in the U.S. or on foreign soil.", simply locating a U.S. operated server offshore providers are fewer benefit than it used to provide.

There is also new legislation in the U.S. (enacted in April of 2018) related to liability, notwithstanding Section 230, in certain instances potentially related to prostitution and human trafficking, called [FOSTA-SESTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_Enabling_Sex_Traffickers_Act), which among other things, resulted in the demise of the website "Backdoor" which made most of its money and earned most of its revenues by offering advertisements for people pitching prostitution thinly veiled as escort services that had defeated many prior civil charges and even some criminal charges as a result of Section 230. As [Vox explains](https://www.vox.com/culture/2018/4/13/17172762/fosta-sesta-backpage-230-internet-freedom):

> FOSTA-SESTA creates an exception to Section 230 that means website
>   publishers would be responsible if third parties are found to be
>   posting ads for prostitution — including consensual sex work — on
>   their platforms.

If you are U.S. based and you don't respect these laws then you are basically part of the [Dark Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_web), and are vulnerable to being shut down, if you site can be located on the Internet in a manner sufficient for law enforcement officials to intervene, and can result in you being criminally prosecuted personally, if law enforcement can link you to your network.

So, this is a course of action you should only undertake if you are either an ideological true believer in making information "free" from legal regulation, or you can make it profitable enough to make the risk worth it.

Comment: thank you, Sir, what about this question, would you kindly share your knowledge on this https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/30215/what-if-i-host-popcorn-time-a-torrent-sharing-platform

Comment: @Tuna I don't understand the technical aspects of that question well enough to provide an answer that I am comfortable is correct.  In my family, I became the lawyer and my brother got the IT genius that I most obviously lack.