# How to prevent legal issues when allowing anonymous users to upload arbitrary content?

Tags: internet, software, anonymization

A website like https://cloudconvert.com allows any **anonymous user** to upload arbitrary video/audio/file and convert it to another format. It seems to save the file temporarily for 2 hours before deletion. I have seen other similar sites do the same (delete after a short period, allowing arbitrary anonymous users to do uploads, etc.).

What are the legal ramifications of this and how can you prevent legal problems with this sort of system of allowing anonymous users to upload stuff? Theoretically they could upload illegal videos or images or classified documents or something.

What do these sites do, and what are you supposed to do, if you want to allow anonymous users to upload stuff?

*Came up from asking [Is it safe to use Google Cloud Signed URLs for anonymous user uploads directly from the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77967074/169992) on StackOverflow.*

Comment: Have you looked at anything that came up in this search https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=Section+230 ?

Comment: @Trish nice, I will check that out. Mind narrowing in on the specifics relevant to this question? It seems like a big topic.

Comment: try https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/60124/does-section-230-protect-users-who-distribute-pirated-content?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C88.2842 for a simple start and maybe https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/30210/a-network-of-anonymous-content-sharing/30214#30214 - which might be a dupe?